# Unable to use service method in a directive; tests showing the method is defined on the service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to make a directive that generates *Lorem Ipsum* text in a format that's to my liking. Here is what I have:

```
angular.module('mock.text', [])
  .factory('TextGenerator', function() {
    var words = [/** lots of array elements (lorem ipsum text) **/];
    return {
      createWords: function(wordCount) {
        var wordCount = wordCount;
        var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 199);
        var sentence = words.slice(idx, wordCount);
        sentence.join(' ');
        sentence.charAt(0).toUpperCase();

        return sentence;
      }
    }
  })

  .directive('text', function(TextGenerator) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var words = TextGenerator.createWords(Number(attrs['numWords']));
        scope.words = words;
      },
      scope: {},
      template: '<p> {{words}} </p>'
    }
  });
```

Which is then sent to the main app module:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['mock.text']);
```

I also have a test to check that the service is working:

```
describe('TextGenerator', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    it('should have a createWords method', function() {
        angular.mock.inject(function(TextGenerator) {
            expect(TextGenerator.createWords).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

The test above passes but when I attempt to actually use the directive like this

```
<p text num-words="7"></p>
```

I instead get an error in the console: *undefined is not a function* and the line where it's happening is in the directive definition

```
var words = TextGenerator.createWords(Number(attrs['numWords']));
```

I've tried other methods in an attempt to get to the root of the problem but no luck. Could someone explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine with service, I tired your code as is.
The code is breaking at `sentence.charAt(0).toUpperCase();`
Review `createWords` method properly.

Comment: Yeah. I'd solved that by the time you'd posted your answer. The solution was to specify `sentence.join(' ').charAt(0).toUpperCase()` in one line. Thing is, the error message I got was too misleading; the script should've thrown maybe a syntax error instead of that `undefined is not a function` but this is JavaScript, I guess.